# How do I enable S3 storage for Apache Zeppelin on Amazon EMR?

Tags: amazon-s3, emr, amazon-emr, apache-zeppelin

I am using Apache Zeppelin and Spark on Amazon EMR. I have configured emrfs to use KMS key, and enable server side encryption. I have not been able to configure S3 storage for zeppelin notebooks (0.7.2) using official instruction:

https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.2/storage/storage.html#notebook-storage-in-s3